# How IAAS communicate with PAAS services

Tags: azure, azure-devops, paas, iaas

In one of the interviews I was asked the below question. Does the IAAS communicate with PAAS services over the vnet ?

How IAAS communicate with PAAS services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the IAAS communicate with PAAS services over the vnet ?

Yes, Within the Same Virtual Networks, across the virtual networks via peering or via VPN/Express Route -- Azure PaaS and IaaS services can communicate with each other.

> How IAAS communicate with PAAS services

As long as the services are reachable via an IP/Port, there are numerous methods to communicate /connect like VNet, Express Route, Peering service, Azure DNS, Bastion, etc.

Refer to the [Azure Networking Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/fundamentals/networking-overview) for more information.